# Finding different sum factors of a number

Tags: permutations, combinations, direct-sum

Actual Question : A fair die is thrown k times. What is the probability of sum of k throws to be equal to a number n?

My Work:
Lets have k buckets, fill-in each bucket with value(1-6) so that the sum meets n, for every unique set of bucket values(u) find the no of *combination of arranging the values(x). Sum all x and the probability would be (sum of all x)/(6 power of k).

One way to find u is brute force. Is there any other way for that?

*I am not sure whether to use permutation or combination for that calculation x and I need formula for the same.

Comment: There is no nice closed form.

Comment: For the permutation or combination, which to use I am not sure, I came with the following: k!/(a! b! ....). eg : for k = 6 and n= 14 one of the possibility is (1,1,1,1,6,4) so 6!/((count of 1)!.(count of 6)!.(count of 4)!). Not sure will this work for all scenarios.

Comment: Correction for above  k!/((count of 1)!.(count of 6)!.(count of 4)!) = 6!/4!. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Counting the ways in which a *particular* pattern can occur is not hard, but for large $k$ there are for most $n$ a lot of patterns. For modest $k$ such as $6$ we can make a list, but it is quite a lot of work.

Comment: Is there any alternative method?

Comment: There is a research literature on the distribution of a sum of discrete uniforms. I am not good at searching, but [here is an example.](http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf) One can also get decent approximations. For smallish concrete examples such as $6$ dice, it  is straightforward to write  program that will list and count.

Comment: Are you asking how to find $u$, or how to find $x$ ?

Comment: both $u$ and $x$